# How to Create a PS Script Which connects to SharePoint Doc LIbrary and iterated through all folders and gets all the CSV Files

Tags: powershell

Need a PS Script co connect to SP and get the Folders in a doc lib and read CSV and update/Create New CSVs Create

a sample Powershelll script  which takes SharePoint URL and Document library and iterates through each folder and find CSV files created a new CSV with -PROD string attached to the name

Comment: Welcome to SO, Dheeraj. Please take some time to read the infomration under https://stackoverflow.com/help to understand how SO works. This is an important question, but is off-topic for SO. When you have code that you are trying to make work, come back to SO.

Comment: Ditto what @lit said. Ill get you started you're going to want to use PnP PowerShell: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/
Take a look at `Get-PnPFolderItem` to get started. Get yourself started with a script and come back here and amend your question with issues youre having in the code.